# Hacer que el parámetro por defecto de un método sea el retorno de otro método de la misma clase

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo

Observen el método `intrianglecircle` de la clase `Triangle`, lo que deseo es que este método reciba como parámetro por defecto **`0.05 * self.incircle.radius`**, como está implementado esta funcionando perfectamente pero mi pregunta es: *¿Hay otra manera de hacerlo que no sea esa que hice ?* Si es así, ¿cómo sería?

Acá dejo el código:

- Para la clase **`Circle`**

  ```
  class Circle:

      def __init__(self, center, radius):
          self.center = center
          self.radius = radius
  ```
- Para la clase **`Triangle`**

  ```
  class Triangle:

      def __init__(self, vertices):

          import numpy as np

          # (3, 2) Array of triangle vertices
          self.v = np.array(vertices)

      @property
      def area(self):

          import numpy as np

          # area triangle
          a = abs(np.linalg.det([self.v[1] - self.v[0],
                                 self.v[2] - self.v[0]])) / 2
          return a

      @property
      def lensides(self):

          from scipy.spatial import distance as dst

          # lengths three sides of triangle
          sc = dst.euclidean(self.v[1], self.v[0])
          sb = dst.euclidean(self.v[2], self.v[0])
          sa = dst.euclidean(self.v[1], self.v[2])
          return (sa, sb, sc)

      @property
      def perimeter(self):

          # perimeter triangle
          p = sum(self.lensides)
          return p

      @property
      def incircle(self):

          s = self.lensides
          p = self.perimeter
          a = self.area
          # center of the inscribed circle
          c = (s[0] * self.v[0] + s[1] * self.v[1] +
               s[2] * self.v[2]) / p
          # radius of the inscribed circle
          r = 2 * a / p
          return Circle(c, r)

      def intrianglecircle(self, radius=None):

          import numpy as np

          if not radius:
              self.radius = 0.05 * self.incircle.radius
          else:
              self.radius = radius
          # random number [0, 1]
          r1, r2 = np.random.random(), np.random.random()
          # random x-coordinate
          px = (1-np.sqrt(r1))*self.v[0][0]+(np.sqrt(r1)*(1-r2)) * \
               self.v[1][0]+(np.sqrt(r1)*r2)*self.v[2][0]
          # y-coordinate
          py = (1-np.sqrt(r1))*self.v[0][1]+(np.sqrt(r1)*(1-r2)) * \
                 self.v[1][1]+(np.sqrt(r1)*r2)*self.v[2][1]
          # random center circle
          self.center = np.array([px, py])
          return Circle(self.center, self.radius)
  ```

Por ejemplo, ¿podría hacer directamente esto?:

```
def intrianglecircle(self, radius= 0.05 * self.incircle.radius):
```

Comment: Andrés, lo que estás haciendo es correcto, tal vez te pienses que  sería interesante poder definir el parámetro `radius` directamente como `0.05 * self.incircle.radius`, pero como es la implementación de OOP de Python, no se puede.

Comment: Patricio, exactamente.... creí que  podría existir alguna manera de hacer eso que acabas de mencionar.

Comment: Andrés, acabo de editar tu pregunta un poco para poder agregar una respuesta un poco más elaborada al respecto. Saludos,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma que estás usando actualmente para manejar un valor `default` de parámetro que ademas eventualmente puede cambiar, es la correcta. Veamos un poco la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/release/3.3.0/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions) acerca de las funciones y los valores por defecto:

> The default values are evaluated at the point of function definition
>   in the defining scope

Esto básicamente significa que el valor por defecto se evalúa únicamente en la instancia de definición de una función. La documentación también aporta este ejemplo bien claro:

```
i = 5
def f(arg=i):
    print(arg)

i = 6
f()
```

La salida será 5 y no 6, además quiere decir que el `default` del parámetro siempre valdrá lo mismo durante todo el tiempo de vida de la función. En tu ejemplo en particular, hacer `def intrianglecircle(self, radius= 0.05 * self.incircle.radius):` es inviable ya que, además, que ya sabemos que el valor `default` será siempre fijo, en la instancia de definición de la función, ni siquiera tenemos creado el objeto al que hace referencia `self`.